# Regex creation to be used on replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use String.replaceAll(regex, String) to replace some chars from a String.

My string is some html and I've been trying to replace 'width: xxxxx.xxxpx;' width 'width: auto;'.

I came up with 2 reg expressions which according to an online reg tester works fine as:

```
width: [0-9]{3,}px; -- match at least 3 digits followed by px;
width: [0-9]{3,}.[0-9]{1,}px; -- match at least 3 digits followed by any char (in my case a .) followed by at least 1 digit and finally px;
```

This has been used in this way in my code:

```
text = text.replaceAll("width: [0-9]{3,}px;", "width: auto;");
text = text.replaceAll("width: [0-9]{3,}.[0-9]{1,}px;", "width: auto;");
```

as an example, I used this text:

```
<p style="margin-left: 10px;"><br></p><p style="margin-left: 10px;">text&nbsp;<span style="text-decoration-line: underline;">not</span>&nbsp;not text.</p><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="width: 1404.8px; z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="height: 100.8px; z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="height: 100.8px; z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="width: 1404.8px; z-index: 90;"></div><table class="ui-resizable" style="width: 1405.6px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><tbody><tr><td class="ui-resizable" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black;">in my opinion both this text is wrong;<br><br><br><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="height: 99.2px; z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="width: 1404px; z-index: 90;"></div></td></tr></tbody></table><p style="margin-left: 10px;">other text:&nbsp;</p><table class="ui-resizable" style="width: 1422.4px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><tbody><tr><td class="ui-resizable" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black;"><p><br></p><p><br></p></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

But this is not working. What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: I think you should use `text.replaceAll(pattern, replacement)` instead of passing text as the replacement right?

Comment: If you remove matches, just use `text = text.replaceAll("width: [0-9]{3,}px;", "");`

Comment: For example `text=text.replaceAll("width: [0-9]{3,}\\.[0-9]{1,}px;","width: auto;");` See https://ideone.com/dlPG2m

Comment: oh yeah that was a typo when i was writing, correcting it now!

Comment: @giovandrea But then it works right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your code, wouldn't it be something like?

```
text = text.replaceAll("width: [0-9]{3,}px;", "width:auto");
text = text.replaceAll("width: [0-9]{3,}.[0-9]{1,}px;", "width:auto");
```

Also I would change the second Regex by adding a backslash before the dot

```
"width: [0-9]{3,}\.[0-9]{1,}px;"
```

And what do you get as result string with your current code?